# Convert strings with least occurrence to the one with the next higher occurrence in matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have following matrix with different strings in each column. The minimum number of different strings in one column is 2, some columns have up to 20 different strings, some columns have only two different strings. I would like to convert strings which occur in frequency 1 or 2 (`<=2`)in each column into the strings with the next higher frequency (`>2`). So, in columns where one factor occurs only once or twice should be converted in the factor with the immediately higher frequency from the same column. If the next higher frequency (`>2`) occurs twice, then just take any of them, it doesn't matter which one. Leave all other columns as they are. In each column, there is always a factor in frequency greater than 2.

My example matrix is:

```
n.mat <- structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "Y", "Y", "M", "M", 
"Y", "Y", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M", "M", "X", "Y", "Y", "F", "F", 
"F", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "G"), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", 
"r8"), NULL))

  [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
r1 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "C" 
r2 "M"  "M"  "M"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r3 "M"  "Y"  "X"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r4 "M"  "Y"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r5 "M"  "F"  "Y"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
r6 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r7 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r8 "Y"  "F"  "F"  "B"  "B"  "G"
```

The desired output:

```
n.mat <- structure(c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "F", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", "F", 
"F", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "E", "E", "D"), .Dim = c(8L, 
6L), .Dimnames = list(c("r1", "r2", "r3", "r4", "r5", "r6", "r7", 
"r8"), NULL))

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
r1 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r2 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r3 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r4 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
r5 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
r6 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r7 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
r8 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "D"
```

I was able to count the frequencies of each factor in each column by this code, but there still is missing the part of converting the strings to the one with the next higher frequency:

```
n.mat<-n.mat[, apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) sort(table(x), decreasing = TRUE)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) {
  tx <- sort(table(x), decreasing=TRUE)
  x[x %in% names(tx[tx <=2])] <- names(rev(tx[names(tx[tx > 2])])[1])
  x
})
#   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# r1 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
# r2 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
# r3 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
# r4 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "D" 
# r5 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "A"  "E" 
# r6 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
# r7 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E" 
# r8 "M"  "F"  "F"  "A"  "B"  "E"
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot, it's almost what I want, except that it converts the strings to the strings with the highest frequency, but I want to convert them to the strings with the next higher frequency. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Luker354 I understand. But how do you discriminate between e.g.  `"D" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E" "E" "D"` and `"E" "D" "D" "D" "E" "E" "E" "E"` for the last column, i.e. when highest and second highest frequency is equal?

Comment: @Luker354 Update code another time, does this work for you now?

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I want. Thank you very much!